# Laravel multi auth custom guard wont log in

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, guard

i make multi guard on my project just for testing both guard have the same persmissions but the other guard wont login

here is the `auth.php`

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'worker' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'workers',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'workers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Worker::class,
    ],
```

and here is the `loginController` btw the `loginattempt` is working i checked it

```
 protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    if(Auth::guard('web')->attempt($this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')))
        return true;
    elseif(Auth::guard('worker')->attempt($this->credentials($request),$request->filled('remember'))){
        return true;
    }
}
```

and here is my web routes

```php
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'album.index', 'uses' => 'AlbumController@index']);
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('logout', 'Controller@customLogout')->name('customLogout');

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'album'], function () {
        Route::get('/showAllAlbums', ['as' => 'album.showAllAlbums', 'uses' => 'AlbumController@showAllAlbums']);
        Route::get('create', ['as' => 'album.create', 'uses' => 'AlbumController@create']);
        Route::post('create', ['as' => 'album.store', 'uses' => 'AlbumController@store']);
        Route::get('/{id}', ['as' => 'album.show', 'uses' => 'AlbumController@show']);
        Route::get('delete/{id}', ['as' => 'album.destroy', 'uses' => 'AlbumController@destroy']);

        // upload Photos Routes
        Route::get('/uploadPhoto/{id}', ['as' => 'photo.create', 'uses' => 'PhotoController@create']);
        Route::post('/uploadPhoto', ['as' => 'photo.store', 'uses' => 'PhotoController@store']);

    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'photo'], function () {
        Route::get('/{id}', ['as' => 'photo.show', 'uses' => 'PhotoController@show']);
        Route::get('delete/{id}', ['as' => 'photo.destroy', 'uses' => 'PhotoController@destroy']);
    });
});
```

Comment: Wheres your worker model?

Comment: `
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Auth;

class Worker extends Auth
{
    //
    protected $fillable=['name','email','password'];
}
`

Comment: but i didn't edit anything in the env file